# Laravel Eloquent get all with constrained relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been using Eloquent for just a little while now and I can't figure out how to accomplish this. Say I have the usual Posts, Users, and Comments relationships and I want to return a list of all posts and *within that list* also indicate which ones the logged in user has commented on.

By querying with `whereHas()` or `with()`I've been able to return *only* the posts with the user's comments, or all posts with *all* users' comments. But how would I get *all* posts with *only* the auth user's comments? Or even just a Boolean indicating the presence of a user comment.

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward, I just haven't been able to dig up an answer in the docs or on these boards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments',function($commentQuery){
            $commentQuery->whereHas('user',function($userQuery){
                $userQuery->where('id',Auth::user()->id);
            });
        })->get();
```

Comment: It seems like the answer is some kind of nested query, but this one still only returns Posts with the Auth/User comments, and not the rest.

Comment: @JonathanMarasco I think I misunderstood the question. to be sure you want to be able to tell if a certain `Post` object has comment(s) that were posted by the authenticated user, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Yes that's correct - I want to return a list of _all_ posts, with _only_ the posts with comments by the auth user indicated. According to the docs `whereHas()` "adds a count/exists condition to the query" which limits the results. I think what I need is something more like `with()` which eager loads the relationship, but which as I understand it takes no parameters.